# Mapping through multiple arrays of objects and comparing ids

Tags: reactjs, typescript, performance, loops, nested

So I have a bit of a dilemma. I am creating a forum and I am calling 3 different API's. Suppose I have multiple JSONs:

```
let forumPost= [{  
"userId": 1,
"postId": 1,
"postTitle": "I am the post title",
"postBody": "I am the post body"
}]

let forumUser= [{  
"userId": 1,
"name": "Someone Someone",
"username": "Som",
}]

let forumComment = [{  
"postId": 7,
"userId" : 10,
"body": "I don't like your post",
}]
```

I would now like to create something like this:

```
Post title
  Post body
By user
-------------
CommentUser: CommentBody
CommentUser: CommentBody
```

In order to do this I am currently sort of doing nest mapping 3 times 3 different arrays of objects and comparing id's so:

```
forumPost.map(...
 forumUser.map(...
   forumComment.filter(...
       (post.userId === user.userId){
        <div>...</div>
        }
```

I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of mapping and comparing multiple nested objects in vanilla ReactJS?

Comment: if you transform your user and comment data to a hashMap then you can get it in O(1) time during the rendering time

Comment: What you can do is merge data efficiently before saving it to state then perform memorization if necessary.

Comment: If this needs to be done on the frontend, you can pretty much always expect some level of nesting. These kind of tasks are always going to be very verbose using Javascript.

If this data is served by a backend or stored in a RDBMS, I would suggesting doing it there with some kind of `JOIN` so the frontend doesn't need to worry about this.

Comment: @MrDiggles I have solved this with nesting but into multiple functions. It seems to be the easiest solution since it has to be solved in frontend. I agree with you :)